# Pink Tiled Map with Openlayers and Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2

I'm having a problem with the pink tiles when trying to display a map.
I'm using Geoserver 2.6. In the main html page, I reference to Openlayers with:

`<script src="openlayers/lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>`

This is how I define my layer:

```
new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("dim_province",
                    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", {
                        layers: "dw1:dim_province",
                        transparent: true,
                        format: "image/gif"
                    }, {
                        isBaseLayer: false,
                        buffer: 0,
                        visibility: false
                    }
                ),
```

The layer is displayed with no problem on `Geoserver>preview` as OpenLayers, however It shows a pink tile image when I'm running the html page.

Comment: Try using a tool like Fiddler to examine the request to and response from Geoserver. That way you'll be able to see if the server is getting the correct parameters sent to it and if it's throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Some fairly obvious things to check:

1) try replacing "localhost" with your IP address, especially if you are running your webmap off of another machine (e.g. Geoserver on guest, webmap on host);

2) verify read/write permissions for the folder containing the dataset;

3) Check the code of the openlayers preview and compare to your code. Likewise, note that Geoserver previews use OL2, not OL3;

4) Your code should look like this for your layer in OL3:

```
var lyr_layerName = new ol.layer.Tile({
     source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
     url: "http://X.X.X.X:8080/geoserver/ows?version%3D1.3.0%26",
     params: {"LAYERS": "LayerName", "TILED": "true"},
     })),
     title: "LayerName"
     });
```

5) If you're really having trouble, try using the "Export to OpenLayers" QGIS plugin. [Available here, but easily downloadable via QGIS plugin installer](https://github.com/volaya/qgis-ol3)

Comment: OP asked to do this in OL2.

Comment: Aside: Export to Openlayers 3 is now qgis2web, which can also export to a Leaflet webmap.